# How to add new option in WYSiWYG editor magento

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg, tinymce

i want to add new option in WYSiWYG editor like list bullet & list number.
Is there is any way to add List square option in magento WySiWYG editor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you edit **js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js** you can add the advanced list plugin which will give you a little drop down on the list icon in the toolbar. You can change the list style type using that drop down.

You need to find `getSettings: function(mode)` in **setup.js** and add `advlist` in the value of `var plugins`

```
 getSettings: function(mode)
    {
        var plugins = 'inlinepopups,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,advhr,advimage,advlist,emotions,iespell,media,searchreplace,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras';
```

You will then see this on the toolbar
[image]

**Do this on a dev site first**

Comment: I can't see any way of over-riding this in a local theme so I am aware that I'm advising you to edit a core file.